# Can we run SFTP File upload scenario using Gatling

Tags: gatling

I'm Just interested whether if we create a Scala function to upload file to sftp location can we run it using Gatling executer ?

Answer (score 0):

I believe Gatling does not support SFTP protocol.

Comment: As Gatling's creator, I confirm.

Comment: But I was able to do it with a workaround used jcraft within a session to upload files to sftp location only thing is I will not be able to collect response time but will be able to simulate the load